# Simplest way to save and load information c#

Tags: c#, serialization, save, loading

I have a WPF C# application. 
I need it to be able to save 'Products'. These products will have a Product name, Customer name, and firmware location. This is my current code for saving and loading however it is not working. I'm thinking of trying a different approach to it all together:

```
public class Product
{
    private string productName;
    private string customerName;
    private string firmwareLocation;

    public string getProductName()
    {
        return productName;
    }

    public bool setProductName(string inputProductName)
    {
        productName = inputProductName;
        return true;
    }

    public string getCustomerName()
    {
        return customerName;
    }

    public bool setCustomerName(string inputCustomerName)
    {
        customerName = inputCustomerName;
        return true;
    }

    public string getFirmwareLocation()
    {
        return firmwareLocation;
    }

    public bool setFirmwareLocation(string inputFirmwareLocation)
    {
        inputFirmwareLocation = firmwareLocation;
        return true;
    }

    public Product(string inProductName, string inCustomerName, string inFirmwareLocation)
    {
        inProductName = productName;
        inCustomerName = customerName;
        inFirmwareLocation = firmwareLocation;
    }

    public void Save(TextWriter textOut)
    {
        textOut.WriteLineAsync(productName);
        textOut.WriteLineAsync(customerName);
        textOut.WriteLineAsync(firmwareLocation);
    }

    public bool Save(string filename)
    {
        TextWriter textOut = null;
        try
        {
            textOut = new StreamWriter(filename);
            Save(textOut);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textOut != null)
            {
                textOut.Close();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static Product Load (string filename)
    {
        Product result = null;
        System.IO.TextReader textIn = null;

        try
        {
            textIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            string productNameText = textIn.ReadLine();
            string customerNameText = textIn.ReadLine();
            string firmwareLocationText = textIn.ReadLine();
            result = new Product(productNameText, customerNameText, firmwareLocationText);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textIn != null) textIn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "_however it is not working_" Why it is not working?

Comment: Define "not working." Can you be more specific? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens? Also, why aren't you just using one of the standard .NET serializers/deserializers for this? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The code above has nothing to do with WPF.

Comment: More specificity is best. Any exceptions occuring, have you debugged, what exactly are you trying to save to?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what you mean by "not working" but I'd suggest that you just use the standard .NET serialization/deserialization libraries for this rather than trying to reinvent the wheel. There's no need to do anything custom here. See the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656716.aspx

As a side note, why are you using getX() and setX() methods instead of properties? It's not standard C#. For example, the following:

```
private string productName;

public string getProductName()
{
    return productName;
}

public bool setProductName(string inputProductName)
{
    productName = inputProductName;
    return true;
}
```

should be

```
public string ProductName
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

I'm guessing that one of the reasons your code isn't working is that it has multiple *glaring* race conditions. For example, all 3 of your writes are asynchronous and fired off right after the other; there's no guarantee that the previous one will be done when you start the next one. It's not even clear to me that you're guaranteed to write the lines in a particular order (which you're counting to be the case in your deserialization logic). It's also completely possible (likely, actually) that you'll close the file in the middle of your write operations.

I'd also suggest a "using" block for the file streams.